# make_shared and abstract polymorphism

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr

Is there any way I can use `make_shared` instead of `shared_ptr` for abstract types?

Example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void fooFunc() = 0;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    void fooFunc() {};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Foo> > vec;

    vec.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Bar()));
    //vec.push_back(std::make_shared<Foo>(new Bar())); //doesn't work because Foo is abstract

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `std::static_pointer_cast` if you want to be explicitly mentioning the cast:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::static_pointer_cast<Foo>(std::make_shared<Bar>()));
}
```

But it also works without it:

```
vec.push_back(std::make_shared<Bar>());
```

Here's a demo showing the behaviour: [Demo](http://ideone.com/EgMELj)

I'd recommend not to use `std::make_shared` in combination with `new`. There is a performance concern here and in my opinion it's a good thing to avoid unbalanced `new` / `delete`s.

Comment: `make_shared` with `new` is completely wrong anyways - `make_shared` already allocates the storage for the object.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up here because I didn't specify my inheritance as public. So I had:

```cpp
class Bar : Foo
```

instead of:

```cpp
class Bar : public Foo
```

Adding the public made `shared_ptr<Foo> foo = make_shared<Bar>(...)` work as expected